# How to write to a server/URL in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, url, serialization

Basically, how can I store data in a URL that can be accessed by other devices?

This would be similar to how Instagram works, where people can see the pictures that others post, even though the files are not stored locally on the user's device.

This could also be a way to create high score leaderboards in a game without using GameCenter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ask a lot in one question. It needs more than iOS, it need iOS app + Server scripts (php or RoR & co + storage & co).

Answer (score 0):

NSURLRequest class is better to use to perform request by URL. So, if you have some RESTful backend by the URL that accept POST data you will be able to push binaries. You can find code iOS example for request similar to yours by following URL - [Send image to server as binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323709/send-image-to-server-as-binary-data)

For the server side I would suggest to take a look into node.js direction (http://nodejs.org)

Answer (score 0):

You need some form of server support, like php, asp etc.
Have a look at [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and for iOS have a look at [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or even better, [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).