# How to send image to server with url in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I need to send a image to server with Url the url looks as below

http://somewebsite.com:8080/app/api/fappname/newUser/1/Delhi481/cct/12 dk/11588/kmkr/72579/Los/TM/8:00/13:00/28.6100/77.2300/foto1.jpg/null

they asked me to send image in place of foto1.jpg, the code that now i'm using is as below i am sending null inplace of image i'm getting response. can any one send me how to send the image in this url.

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.com:8080/app/api/kkknnmm/newUser/1/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/TM/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@",[inSchoolName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],@"kktt",[inAddressStreet stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],inAddressNo,inAddressState,inZipCode,[inNeighbourhood stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[arrivalHR stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[endingHr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],inlat,inlong,inImg1,inImg2,inImg3];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
NSLog(@"Login Url:%@",str);
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

can any one please help me.

Comment: "I'm getting response". What response are you getting? You haven't explained what is/isn't happening. i.e. there is no question here. Also, have you spoken to the people who created the API and asked them to send you a sample of a successful upload of an image (without null)?

Comment: could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323709/send-image-to-server-as-binary-data

Comment: review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434537/post-image-to-server-in-iphone/16434601#16434601

Comment: what you API expects you to send?

Comment: @Saad Chaudhry  image in data format

Comment: you mean binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your Api Is expecting binary data, I would suggest you to go through these links.

I hope they Will Help you.

[Have A look at this](http://tutorialsios.blogspot.com/2013/08/post-multipart-form-data-using.html) And [this](http://ihoneylocust.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/send-data-to-server-from-ios/)

Comment: feel free if you stuck somewhere