# Nsdata to bytearray conversion. Memory issue and crash on iPad physical device

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, nsdata

I am using the following code to convert nsdata to bytearray. It works fine in simulator. On device, it allocates memory like crazy to 600 MB [on the 'addobject' line inside the loop] and crashes. The file size I am reading is 30 MB. The error I see in output windows is "memory issue". The file is a "zip" file

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];
const unsigned char *bytes = [data bytes];
NSUInteger length = [data length];
NSMutableArray *byteArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {
@autoreleasepool {
         [byteArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[i]]];                                                  }
       }
```

I am using this bytearray inside a NSDictionary and do a "dataWithJSONObject" on the dictionary to post the json to a REST web service.

Comment: why do you want an array of NSNumbers to do that?

Comment: Do you propose a different type John? That code worked fine on simulator so just continued with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more memory efficient way to convert NSData to byte array, see [How to convert NSData to byte array in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone)

If your goal is ultimately to post the binary data to a web service in JSON, try the following:

1. Base64-encode the the data in a String, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468530/2892227). This can be passed in the JSON Body.
2. Alternatively, if you have flexibility on changing the server-side of this transfer, avoid base64-encoded data in a JSON and rather directly post the binary content using an HTTP POST or PUT. This will be more efficient.

For the second approach, I can think of two ways to do this:

- [Here is an example for the scenario of sending an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326432/2892227), but any file type will work so long as you can load it into an NSData object.
- Or, something like this should work

  ```c
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url_here"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
  NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/octet-stream"};
  [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
  [request setHTTPBody:data]
  // Use an URLSession object task to execute the request
  ```

Lastly, if the data can be compressed on the client before encoding and sending, that would be even better!

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you Kevdoran. Your 2nd option worked perfectly. Changed server API to accept httppost.